# Calling a Perl script from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, perl, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox addon and I have a Perl script which I am using to perform a specific task. This Perl script needs to be called from the addon. What would be the best way to implement this? I was thinking of creating a socket program in perl (on my server) to listen for an incoming connection (from my addon) and then calling my required Perl script. But then how would I call this Perl script from the JavaScript in the Firefox addon? Also, is there any better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to set up a proper web server with [Perl CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) support, and use JavaScript and Ajax on the client side to call into your script.

There are plenty of resources online for both of these technologies.

Comment: You should probably spell it out - [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) should be used in the add-on.

Comment: @Mat- Could you point out some good tutorials which discuss this.

Comment: CGI is an option. It has simplicity in its favour, but it also suffers from performance issues. [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) is the current favoured approach and should be at least looked at.