# Wrapping up a Perl script into a webservice

Tags: web-services, perl, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Perl script that can be run from the command line and takes a file as an argument. I want to be able to call this script from my JavaScript (in a Firefox addon). I was planning on using `XMLHttpRequest`. But what is the best way to wrap up my Perl script into a webservice? (Is there any Perl to SOAP convertor?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Perl script from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480908/calling-a-perl-script-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is the best way to wrap up my Perl script into a webservice?

1. Split the existing functionality of the code into a module that does the work and a small wrapper script to add a command line interface
2. Write another wrapper that presents a web interface. (Probably using something like [CGI::Application](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aApplication) (which now supports other interfaces, so you aren't restricted to CGI) or [Web::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Web%3a%3aSimple)).

> (Is there any Perl to SOAP convertor?)

Don't use SOAP.

SOAP is chunky, complex, and covers many many edge cases that are unlikely to be problems for you. Use a light weight RESTful API instead.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a rest(earlier soap) api using java and calling the perl script from that .Would you suggest doing this.

Comment: No. I'd avoid SOAP, and I'd avoid mixing in additional languages (as the interface just introduces more places that errors could creep in).

Comment: Okay. Once i have the CGI set up how would i call it from the javascript. Are there any tutorials for doing this

Comment: [Hundreds.](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript%20http%20request&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=44555ba97bb81f0b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1012&bih=683). I can't recommend a particular one, but do avoid W3Schools.